# Can Linq to entities have an optional Include?

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I'm not sure if I can do this or not, but if I can, I'm not sure the best approach.

I have a model/table called RoleAssignment with a foreign key id that could like to one of two tables (Profile or ProfileSnapshot). I would like to get an enumerable of RoleAssignment that would include whichever one. When I do my linq query, and try to include both tables, I get no records. I believe this is because no record will join to both tables.

Later, I will do something like `if (item.Assignee == null) do something with item.AssigneeSnapshot`.

I was thinking I could do a linq query with Default if Empty, but not sure of the correct syntax.

Here's my model:

```
public class RoleAssignment : BaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int RoleAssignmentId { get; set; }

    public Guid AssigneeId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AssigneeId")]
    public virtual Profile Assignee { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AssigneeId")]
    public virtual ProfileSnapshot AssigneeSnapshot { get; set; }
}
```

And here's what I'm trying with Linq:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("_roleassignmentindex")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public virtual ActionResult _RoleAssignmentIndex(RoleAssignmentFilterViewModel filter)
{
    var rolesAssmnt = db.RoleAssignment
        .Include(r => r.Assignee)
        .Include(r => r.AssigneeSnapshot)
        .Include(r => r.OrganizationAssignedTo)
        .Where(r => r.IsActive);

    if (filter.ProfileToSearch != null && filter.ProfileToSearch != Guid.Empty)
        rolesAssmnt = rolesAssmnt.Where(r => r.AssigneeId == filter.ProfileToSearch);

    if (filter.RoleToSearch != null && filter.RoleToSearch > 0)
        rolesAssmnt = rolesAssmnt.Where(r => r.RoleId == filter.RoleToSearch);

    return View(rolesAssmnt.ToList());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to break down your queries like so:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("_roleassignmentindex")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public virtual ActionResult _RoleAssignmentIndex(RoleAssignmentFilterViewModel filter)
{
    List<RoleAssignment> = null;

    if (filter.ProfileToSearch != null && filter.ProfileToSearch != Guid.Empty)
    {
       rolesAssmnt = db.RoleAssignment
        .Include(r => r.Assignee)
        .Include(r => r.AssigneeSnapshot)
        .Where(r => r.IsActive && r.AssigneeId == filter.ProfileToSearch)
        .ToList();

       rolesAssmnt.AddRange(db.RoleAssignment
        .Include(r => r.Assignee)
        .Include(r => r.OrganizationAssignedTo)
        .Where(r => r.IsActive && r.AssigneeId == filter.ProfileToSearch));            
    }

    else if (filter.RoleToSearch != null && filter.RoleToSearch > 0)
    {
       rolesAssmnt = db.RoleAssignment
        .Include(r => r.Assignee)
        .Include(r => r.AssigneeSnapshot)
        .Where(r => r.IsActive && r.RoleId == filter.RoleToSearch)
        .ToList();

       rolesAssmnt.AddRange(db.RoleAssignment
        .Include(r => r.Assignee)
        .Include(r => r.OrganizationAssignedTo)
        .Where(r => r.IsActive && r.RoleId == filter.RoleToSearch));
    }

    return View(rolesAssmnt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing it like this, but thanks to The Sharp Ninja:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("_roleassignmentindex")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public virtual ActionResult _RoleAssignmentIndex(RoleAssignmentFilterViewModel filter)
{
    List<RoleAssignment> rolesAssmnt = null;

    if (filter.ProfileToSearch != null && filter.ProfileToSearch != Guid.Empty)
    {
        rolesAssmnt = db.RoleAssignment
            .Include(r => r.Assignee)
            .Include(r => r.OrganizationAssignedTo)
            .Where(r => r.IsActive &&
                r.AssigneeId == filter.ProfileToSearch
            ).ToList();

        rolesAssmnt.AddRange(db.RoleAssignment
            .Include(r => r.AssigneeSnapshot)
            .Where(r => r.IsActive &&
                r.AssigneeSnapshot.ProfileId == filter.ProfileToSearch
            ).ToList());
    }
    else
    {
        rolesAssmnt = db.RoleAssignment
            .Include(r => r.Assignee)
            .Include(r => r.OrganizationAssignedTo)
            .Where(r => r.IsActive
            ).ToList();

        rolesAssmnt.AddRange(db.RoleAssignment
            .Include(r => r.AssigneeSnapshot)
            .Where(r => r.IsActive
            ).ToList());
    }

    if (filter.RoleToSearch != null && filter.RoleToSearch > 0)
        rolesAssmnt = rolesAssmnt.Where(r => r.RoleId == filter.RoleToSearch).ToList();

    return View(rolesAssmnt);
}
```